# Strange error php

Tags: php, mysql

Done new si working, but i have this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() [function.mysql-fetch-array]: The result type should be either MYSQL_NUM, MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_BOTH. in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/header.php on line 885
```

In the line 885 , I have this function:

```
878 function AddView($id,$oldviews)
879 {
880 mysql_query("UPDATE banners SET views=".($oldviews+1)." WHERE id=".$id);
881 }
882 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `banners` WHERE state=0");
883 $got=array();
884  mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
885    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, $numass)) {
886        array_push($got, $row);
887 }
```

Comment: First. Use `mysqli`, second, use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {`.

Comment: He would need to use `global $numass` in the function for it to even exist in the function. (If not global already)

Answer (score 3):

What is `$numass`? The second parameter for `mysql_fetch_array()` is supposed to be a flag indicating what format the array should be in.

Comment: I don't konw very good php, $numass I think is number of click

Comment: but in another hosting this is working ( the same script, all files the same)

Comment: @CindySeoLine may be in other hosting errors are suppressed. This is a *warning* not *error*.

Answer (score 1):

What is `$numass`? it seems useless. This is the simplification of your code, and it works perfectly:

```
878 function AddView($id,$oldviews)
879 {
880    mysql_query("UPDATE banners SET views=".($oldviews+1)." WHERE id=".$id);
881 }
882 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `banners` WHERE state=0");
883 $got=array();
884 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
885        array_push($got, $row);
886 }
```

Comment: yes.. new is working... I hope that $numass , it is not necessary.. thank you

Comment: if you don't mind you should click the thick or give vote for the correct answer to make sure it has been solved, so it would save another time answering your question.

Comment: new i have this error:   Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ae_detect_ie() (previously declared in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/config.php:20) in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/config.php on line 25

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of **[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)** should be the type of array that is to be fetched. It's a constant and can take the following values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH.

mysql_fetch_array can be used in three ways:

- mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_NUM
- mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC
- mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_BOTH

Second arguement should be either **MYSQL_NUM** or **MYSQL_ASSOC** or  **MYSQL_BOTH**. It should not be **$numass**.

I guess **numass** is a column name in a `banners` table.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
     array_push($got, $row["numass]");
     ....
```

Comment: nice explanation, could you expand on what it might look like? Example: `MYSQL_NUM` = `array(0=>"",1=>"")`, `MYSQL_ASSOC` = `array("one"=>"","two"=>"")` and `MYSQL_BOTH` = `array(0=>"",1=>"","one"=>,"two"=>""`.

Answer (score 1):

$numass supposed to hold value of any of MYSQL_NUM, MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_BOTH. But in your case its different value.